# How to add culvert in DEM-Raster?

Tags: raster, qgis

Is it possible to edit a DEM raster? I want to insert or add a culvert/outlet like in the sketch. Any other solutions?

- WIN10- QGIS Madeira 3.4.3-

[image: flow path - falsified backwater because missing culvert]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, consider adding more information on subject and be more specific on your issue. Also, it would be nice to provide images right here in your answer. If it's possible.

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations, including plugin and library recommendations, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Such questions are usually closed. See here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289843/can-i-ask-for-code-libraries-and-plugins-on-stack-overflow-or-is-that-better-su

Comment: @ogostos I'd like to "burn" a polyline into the DEM raster. Is it possible to edit the raster itself?